# Android disabled autofocus EditText in ScrollView layout

Tags: android, listview, text

in my Activity I have a scrollview layout with two EditText inside. As soon as I open the activity is focused the EditTextinstead I do not want this to happen automatically.
I found a solution in this forum but not working. I hope you can help me. thanks

```
 ScrollView view = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
view.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
view.setFocusable(true);
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.requestFocusFromTouch();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this attribute for your activity in the manifest file
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"